# Wordpress read more URL options

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now my Wordpress blog is using the `<!--more-->` feature somewhat correct.

It is linking to http://domain.com/2014/05/27/post-name/#more-71

Notice how the #more has a hyphen and post id attached, is there any way to get rid of that and simply have: http://domain.com/2014/05/27/post-name/#more

I don't see anything special in the functions file and the index has the plain-jane:

```
<?php the_content('Read More...'); ?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following code to your functions.php:

```
add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_post_id');
function remove_more_post_id($link) {
    $link = preg_replace('~#more-\d+~', '#more', $link);
    return $link;
}
```